# google chrome silverlight plugin load issue

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome

We have sharepoint 2010 with silverlight. All silverlight sites are loaded into IE9 but some of them cannot be loaded into chrome but they work with IE. I tried to find if there is any error but there is no any exception. It just doesn't load the xap because application start event doesn't fire.
I tried to set reduce xap size from silverlight project but then it doesn't work in IE either.
Could you please help me I could not find anyother solution?
Kind Regards
Reside Ozsoy

Comment: Check if Silverlight is working properly: http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx